# Extracting boundary line from Image in R

Tags: r, boundary

So I got some kind of cross section picture in jpg format I want to work with. For better understanding I just drew a picture, hopefully symbolising well enough kinda how the real pictures will look like:

[image]

At the top of the picture is material A, at the bottom material B.

**Goal: I want to get the Pixels of the boundary line between both materials.**

My way so far:

- I already know how to read pictures with package called `EBImage`
- I also know, that this will result in a matrix with a color value for
  every pixel.
- I thought it would be better to convert the jpeg into a binary picture with only black and white colors.
- I thought filling up the black part below (Material B) and reducing the noise would be nice, so I could use column sums (a sum of 1's) to find the row number where material A touches material B, which should be my searched boundary line (right?).

Problems:

- I don't find filters which fill up the black parts intelligently, in the real pictures, there will be much more noise, which will complicate things even further...
- I am not sure if all this is even necessary, and there is a more efficient way to reach my goal of finding the boundary line

Thank you very much for every tip in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Answers will always be vague when there's no example to work with. I would normally use ImageJ for a task like this but EBImage has the commands that I would use.

From EBImage I would make binary and then erode , dilate, and fill holes (fillHull).

Comment: I do not have the data yet, so it is also vague for me. I am just doing some preperation work. I tried: 
kern = makeBrush(10, shape='diamond')
x= erode(x, kern)
x= dilate(x, kern)
display(x) and it already gave me a very good output for my self drawn picture. I havent even used the fillHull yet.

z=c(320-rowSums(x))
plot (z) gave me what i wanted. Hopefully this will work as expected with the real data once i get it. Thank you very much for the help, i am going to try the svm approach from @Greg Snow to see how well it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Your picture looks like it might be a candidate for a [support vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).  There are a couple of packages for R with `svm` functions, one is e1071.

Comment: I just tried to run the unedited code from the package description of the svm function on the binary picture too see what happens:

svm=svm(x, y = NULL, scale = TRUE, type = NULL, kernel = "radial", degree = 3, gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 1 else 1 / ncol(x), coef0 = 0, cost = 1, nu = 0.5, class.weights = NULL, cachesize = 40, tolerance = 0.001, epsilon = 0.1, shrinking = TRUE, cross = 0, probability = FALSE, fitted = TRUE, subset, na.action = na.omit)

suprisingly works but object svm after it is a "list of 30", since i want a vector which is the boundary line, what is this list auf 30?!

Comment: ok: i guess you get suporting vectors which are some of the searched pixels and then you have to decide which method you wanna use to "connect the dots" right?!

Comment: @Mmadsen, the `xspline` function may be of use for connecting the dots, at least for graphing.  Finding a functional form of the line that connects will require thought about what functional forms you are willing to work with.